# unable to change junit version from 3.8.1 to 4.11 using maven on eclipse kepler

Tags: maven, junit4, eclipse-kepler

i created a simple maven java project on eclipse kepler.
    I wrote a simple JUnit (version 4) test. I can run it from Eclipse, but not from the pom.xml (alt-click, Run as, Maven Test). I suppose I need to tell Maven to search for that class, but I just don't know how.

```
with default junit version 3.8.1, mvn test works fine but failing on only eclipse when changed to 4.11. this worked on command promt.

my pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.seleniumsimplified.webdriver</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdriverbasics</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>webdriverbasics</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

error :
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.10/surefire-junit4-2.10.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.819s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 02 19:25:36 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/210M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project webdriverbasics: Unable to generate classpath: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit4:jar:2.10: Failed to retrieve POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit4:jar:2.10: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit4:pom:2.10 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.10/surefire-junit4-2.10.pom
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit4:jar:2.10
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) dummy:dummy:jar:1.0: UnresolvedAddressException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException


workarounds that i tried :
1) tried adding  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

2) changed test file name from AppTest.java to TestApp.java
3) commented <scope>test</test>
4) selected Upgrade Maven project

but nothing is helping. i am new to Maven.
please guide. thanks in advance :)
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition

> **pluginManagement**: is an element that is seen along side plugins. Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way, ***except that rather than configuring plugin information for this particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one***.

But you need to configure plug-in in current project, so

```
<project ...
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
...
<build>
</project>
```

Specifying the version for surefire-junit is not required - maven has some [rules](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html) around it, but I prefer the clarity.

You still need a `<scope>test</test>` for junit dependency though.